# Project To using Automapper

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I'm having an issue with automapper that is causing a "The type appears in two structurally incompatible initialization within a single linq to entities query" error.

I'm trying to `ProjectTo<School>` a query to retrieve a list of (IQueryable) schools.

```
public IQueryable<School> GetSchools(string state = "", string county = "")
{                  
    return _adapter.GetSchools(state, county).ProjectTo<School>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
}
```

The issue is that each school contains a list of `Teacher` and each `Teacher` contains a list of `Class` and each `Class` contains a list of `Student` and each `Student` contains a list of `TestHistories` and when the query is generated by automapper's `ProjectTo<>` it tries to create two different `Student` initializations, one with the list of `TestHistories` and one without:

```
.Lambda #Lambda10<System.Func`2[CoolTools4School.Data.Student,CoolTools4School.Library.Models.Student]>(CoolTools4School.Data.Student $dto)
{
.New CoolTools4School.Library.Models.Student(){
    StudentId = $dto.StudentId,
    Name = $dto.Name,
    ClassId = $dto.ClassId,
    Gender = $dto.Gender,
    TestHistories = .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(.Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(
            $dto.TestHistories,
            .Lambda #Lambda12<System.Func`2[CoolTools4School.Data.TestHistory,CoolTools4School.Library.Models.TestHistory]>))
}
```

}

```
.Lambda #Lambda11<System.Func`2[CoolTools4School.Data.Student,CoolTools4School.Library.Models.Student]>(CoolTools4School.Data.Student $dto)
{
.New CoolTools4School.Library.Models.Student(){
    StudentId = $dto.StudentId,
    Name = $dto.Name,
    ClassId = $dto.ClassId,
    Gender = $dto.Gender
}
```

}

I don't want to ignore the test histories in the config or anything because I'll need those later, but I don't know how to get the query to create the two new `Student` queries the same way without ignoring the test history when configuring.

Student class looks like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? ClassId { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    public Class Class { get; set; }
    public List<TestHistory> TestHistories { get; set; } = new List<TestHistory>();
}
```

Test history class looks like this:

```
public class TestHistory
{
    public Guid TestHistoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ElaspedTime { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public Guid? StudentId { get; set; }
    public Guid? TestId { get; set; }

    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping code is pretty generic:

```
builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Data.Teacher, Models.Teacher>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Data.Student, Models.Student>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Data.Test, Models.Test>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Data.TestHistory, Models.TestHistory>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Data.Question, Models.Question>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Data.School, Models.School>().ReverseMap();
            cfg.CreateMap<Class, Models.Class>().ReverseMap();
            //etc.
        }));
```

BTW, this following code works, I'm just looking for a way to use `ProjectTo<>` and not have to do it this way:

```
public IQueryable<School> GetSchools(string state = "", string county = "")
{
    var schools = _adapter.GetSchools(state, county);

    var list = new List<School>();
    foreach (var school in schools)
    {
        list.Add(_mapper.Map<School>(school));
    }
    return list.AsQueryable();    
}
```

EDIT: As @rossbush points out, this also works:

```
public IQueryable<School> GetSchools(string state = "", string county = "")
{
    return _mapper.Map<List<School>>(_adapter.GetSchools(state, county)).AsQueryable();            
}
```

Comment: Not using ProjectTo<>, however , here is one way to map configured lists -->  List<Model.School> schools = Mapper.Map<List<Domain.School>, List<Model.School>>(_adapter.GetSchools(state, county));

Comment: @RossBush I can't do that unless I do this: `_mapper.Map<List<Data.School, Model.School>>(_adapter.GetSchools(state, county).ToList())`. I would have to call `ToList()` on the `IQueryable` which would generate that SQL with the incompatible stuff above and error out.

Comment: Barry Franklin -Yes it would. Please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @RossBush Actually it works if you change it to this: `return _mapper.Map<List<School>>(_adapter.GetSchools(state, county)).AsQueryable();`, which would save me some "ForEaching". But it still doesn't feel as clean as just using `ProjectTo<>`

Comment: I was scratching my head at first because you can - List --> IEnumerable --> IQueryable.

Comment: Where is the second projection (lambda) used? When mapping `TestHistory.Student` property? Can we see the `Models.TestHistory` class?

Comment: @IvanStoev The `Models.TestHistory` class is shown above. I'm not sure where the second lambda is used, but right after that is a lamba to pull test histories by themselves. So it is `Student` with `Histories`, `Student` without `Histories`, and then `Histories` in the lambda order... `Histories` is the last one.

Comment: Well, there must be a circular reference or something. If the above is `Models.TestHistory`, then can we see the `Data.TestHistory`? You use one and the same class names, so I was assuming `Data` is EF object (source) and `Models` are the targets of `ProjectTo`, no? I think you need to remove the inverse property from targets, i.e. if `Student` has a collection of `TestHistory`, then `TestHistory` should not have `Student` property. At least for `ProjectTo`, `Map` can resolve circular references.

Comment: I've observed that AutoMapper (6.1.1) just ignores a circular reference when calling `ProjectTo`: the reference is just `null` (which in itself is disputable behavior, but anyway, it doesn't seem to cause this issue).

Comment: @GertArnold I'm using 6.2.2, so they must have 'fixed' that.

Comment: In 6.2.2 I see the same behavior: list items with back references to the list owner have `null` references when using `ProjectTo`, not when using 'Map`.